# Extracting basename from a a string with mixed slashes

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, cygwin, basename

I am trying to extract the basename *abcd.txt* from the following, which I am getting from a join operation performed on a list :

```
path = "my/python/is/working"
list = ["abcd","efgh","ijkl"]
path_of_each_file = [path + "\\" + x for x in list]
```

Therefore the list looks like :

```
path[0] = ["my/python/is/working\\abcd.txt","my/python/is/working\\abcd.txt","my/python/is/working\\abcd.txt"]
```

I am using the following to get the base name from each ekement of the list :

```
name_base = os.path.basename(path[0])
```

But the output which  I get is :

```
name_base = working\\abcd.txt
```

I just need ***abcd.txt*** as my base name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `re.split(r'\\|\/', "my/python/is/working\\abcd.txt")[-1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern way:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("my/python/is/working")
flist = ["abcd.txt","efgh.txt","ijkl.txt"]
path_of_each_file = [path / x for x in flist]

for p in path_of_each_file:
    print(p.name)
```

- use the pathlib module for portability.
- `list` is the type name of a list object, not recommended to use as a variable name.
- "/" is the operator to join Path objects.
- using `for elem in alist: ...` is more pythonic.
- `np.name` is the equivalent of `os.path.basname(op)` when using pathlib.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your issue correctly, the following code should help you:

```
path = "my/python/is/working"
list = ["abcd.txt","efgh.txt","ijkl.txt"]
path_of_each_file = [path + "\\" + x for x in list]

for i in range(len(path_of_each_file)):
    print(os.path.basename(path_of_each_file[i]))
```

Output:

```
abcd.txt
efgh.txt
ijkl.txt
```